# If $f:\;[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuously differentiable, then it is uniformly differentiable.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, uniform-continuity

Hi I need help with this exercise:

> Let $f:\;[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that  $f'$ is continuous on $(a,b)$. Prove for all $\epsilon>0$ there exist $\delta>0$ such that $$\left|\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}-f'(x)\right|<\epsilon$$ if $0<|t-x|<\delta$, $\ $ $a<x,t\leq b$.

Please if you can, get me some ideas for do this. I know I need do it for definition, but I don't know how to start.

Comment: Hint: Use the fact that $f'$ is uniformly continuous on $[a, b]$.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume that $f'$ continuous on all of $[a,b]$. Then $f'$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$.

Given an $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|f'(y)-f'(x)|<\epsilon$ whenever $x$, $y\in[a,b]$ and $|y-x|<\delta$. Assume that $t$, $x\in[a,b]$ with $0<|t-x|<\delta$. Then there is a $y$ between $t$ and $x$ such that $${f(t)-f(x)\over t-x}=f'(y)\ .$$
Since $|y-x|\leq |t-x|<\delta$ we can be sure that $|f'(y)-f'(x)|<\epsilon$, and the claim follows.

But one can say more:

**Theorem.** *There is a continuous function $\phi:\>[a,b]^2\to{\mathbb R}$ such that*
$$\phi(x,y)={f(y)-f(x)\over y-x}\quad(y\ne x),\qquad\phi(x,x)=f'(x)\ .$$
*Proof.* Write
$$f(y)-f(x)=\int_x^y f'(t)\>dt=(y-x)\int_0^1f'\bigl((1-\tau)x+\tau y\bigr)\>d\tau\ .$$
It follows that
$\phi(x,y):=\int_0^1f'\bigl((1-\tau)x+\tau y\bigr)\>d\tau$ does the job.

Comment: Excellent, but i can't use integration... for this proof :l @Christian Blatter